# '... incorrectly extends base class static side' error when overriding static field in derived class

Tags: inheritance, typescript, static-variables

Overriding static field in derived class causes

> error TS2417: Build:Class static side 'typeof TDerived' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof TBase'.

Is this a legit error case?

```typescript
class TBase
{
  private static s_field = 'something';

  public constructor() {}
}

class TDerived extends TBase
{
  private static s_field = 'something else'; // commenting this line fixes error

  public constructor()
  {
    super();
  }
}
```

How should i deal with static fields then?
The only workaround right now would be to prepend class name to every static field name which is an exceptionally ugly solution.

```typescript
private static TBase_s_field = 'something';
...
private static TDerived_s_field = 'something else';
```

ps using typescript 2.0.3

Answer (score 2):

You cannot redeclare a `private` field in a derived class. Use `protected` if you intend for derived classes to be able to redeclare or access the field.

This is enforced because static methods are also available in the derived class. For example, this code does something unexpected (if we ignore the compile error):

```
class Base {
    private static foo = 'base';

    static printName() {
        // Should always print 'base' because no one
        // else has access to change 'foo'
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    private static foo = 'derived';
}
// Will actually print 'derived'
Derived.printName();
```

Comment: Any background behind this restriction? It opposes common inheritance practice from other languages.

Comment: Properties in JavaScript all go into the same string-based lookup table, so there's no way to have two fields with the same name be stored in the same logical object with two different addresses the way you could in languages which can emit differing lookup tables for resolution

Comment: In this case we are actually trying to store two fields with the same name in two different objects. Basically adding these static fields suppose to be equivalent to

     Object.defineProperty(TBase, "s_field", {value: 'something'});
  Object.defineProperty(TDerived, "s_field", {value: 'something else'});

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The problem comes when you have a method in the base class invoked through the derived class (static methods are inherited as well) -- that method will read the "wrong" private value.

Comment: No, it won't. Javascript uses prototype-base inheritance so static fields in derived class static side will always properly override static fields in base class static side (which will be still available by accessing base class static side directly). When a Javascript interpreter finds that TDerived has s_field it simply won't go deeper and check whether s_field exists in TDerived.prototype. The only difference private modified makes (at least suppose to make) is forcing typescript compiler to prohibit access to s_field outside of class code (at compile time).

Comment: I know how JavaScript works. Read the non-working code I posted.